# How can I get the entity name from inside a Doctrine repository?

Tags: doctrine, repository, entity

I'm aware of [how to get an entity name from outside of a repository](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8245157/526495), but how about if I'm inside?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use `$this->getClassMetadata()->getTableName();`